# How to reduce if conditions on Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In this program, I look for a file on the hard drive to choose by name, extension, name and extension, until the code became large, I wanted to know how to reduce it a little.
How to reduce if conditions number of lines in Ruby?
What is the best way to reduce the following condition in Ruby?

```
require "colorize"

new_name_file = {}

loop do

    puts 
    puts "Will we search for the file by name(1), extension(2), name extension(3) or exit programm(4)?"
    print "\n>>>>>> ".magenta
    name_extension = gets.to_i

    if name_extension == 1  # =========== search file name =================
        puts "Enter file name (test, lesson, ruby....etc.) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan

        file_name = gets.strip.downcase


        puts "Name the hard drive on which we will search for the file(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

        # search file hdd
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_name}.*")

    elsif name_extension == 2 # ========= search by file extension =============

        puts "Enter file extension(txt, rb, jpg, csv, json) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan
        file_extension = gets.strip.downcase

        # on which drive we will search put the letter
        puts "Name the hard drive on which we will search for the file(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize


        # search file hdd
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/*.#{file_extension}") 

    elsif name_extension == 3 # ========= search by name and file extension =============

        puts "Enter a name and file extension(test.txt, test.rb, test.jpg, test.csv, test.json..etc) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan
        file_extension_name = gets.strip

        # on which drive we will search put the letter
        puts "Name the hard drive on which we will search for the file(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

        # search file hdd   
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_extension_name}") 

    elsif name_extension == 4
        puts "Exit programm".red
        exit

    end

    contents.each do |txt_name|
        z_name =  File.basename(txt_name)  # file name
        path = File.expand_path(txt_name)  # path file
        new_name_file[z_name] = path       # everything in the hash

    end

    new_name_file.each do |k, v|           # hash output
        puts "file : ".cyan + "#{k} " + " path:".cyan +  "#{v}"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Rubyize this code a lot by trimming down what the main loop does and focus on the job of getting input and delegating:

```
class Tester
  def select
    loop do
      puts 
      puts "Will we search for the file by name(1), extension(2), name extension(3) or exit programm(4)?"
      print "\n>>>>>> "

      input = gets.chomp
      search_method = "search_#{input}"

      if (respond_to?(search_method))
        contents = send(search_method)

        contents.each do |txt_name|
          z_name =  File.basename(txt_name)  # file name
          path = File.expand_path(txt_name)  # path file
          new_name_file[z_name] = path       # everything in the hash
        end
      else
        puts "Unknown input: #{input.inspect}, method #{search_method} not defined."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can engage this with:

```
Tester.new.select
```

This *dynamically dispatches* to methods that follow a simple naming 
convention. To add another method, define one:

```
def search_1
  puts "Enter file name (test, lesson, ruby....etc.) "
  print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan

  file_name = gets.strip.downcase


  puts "Name the hard drive on which we will search for the file(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
  print "\n>>>>>> ".green
  hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

  # search file hdd
  Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_name}.*")
end
```

These methods should return the contents to be displayed. That's pretty simple.

You can take this a step further by defining *classes* instead of *methods* where you can instantiate them and iterate over their results, moving this a lot closer to recommended [object-oriented design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Comment: I tried your code, but what to write in the search? the name of the method does not search and the file name does not want to see the method either

Comment: I entered the code as you have, I enter the name of the method, method_1 "Unknown input.

Comment: the problem here seems to me  if (respond_to?(search_method))

Comment: The name should be `search_1` not `method_1`. This would work better inside a class.

Comment: everything is great, I understand, you wrote the code, as I originally searched by number, I don’t understand how to see the search_1 function, they don’t see the class with the method! here is the location of the code https://paste2.org/LffDGVgV

Comment: The `search_1` method must go inside the class so it can be found.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the code inside the conditions in a method:

```
    def process_file(file_types)
        puts "Enter file name (#{file_types.join(',')}....etc.) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan

        file_name = gets.strip.downcase


        puts "Name the hard drive on which we will search for the file(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

        # search file hdd
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_name}.*")
    end
    file_types = {
      "1" => ['test', 'lesson', 'ruby']
      "2" => 
    }

   loop do
      puts 
      puts "Will we search for the file by name(1), extension(2), name extension(3) or exit programm(4)?"
      print "\n>>>>>> ".magenta
      name_extension = gets
      if name_extension == '4'
        puts "Exit programm".red
        exit
      end

      process_file(file_types[name_extension])
   end
```

Comment: You forgot `.chomp` on `name_extension = gets`. A small thing, but it may be preferable to write `file_types = { '1'=>'Enter file name (test, lesson, ruby....etc.)', '2'=>... }`.

Comment: ```contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_name}.*")```

Comment: don't you have to change? you have the same

Comment: ```"#{file_name}.*"  and  " #{*.extension}"```